# How to I correctly specify the following set of sets of edges of a graph

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, first-order-logic, satisfiability

I have a directed, edge-labled, loop-allowed, double-edge-disallowed (with different label allowed, with same disallowed that is) Graph $G$ with Vertices $v\in V_G$ and Edges $e\in E_G$. Each edge gets assigned a sourcenode, targetnode and label via the functions src, tgt and lab. I want to express the set of sets of edges with same src and tgt nodes.
I think $\bigcup_{(v_1,v_2)\in V_G^2}\{\{e\in E_G:src(e)=v_1\wedge tgt(e)=v_2\}\}$ might be right, but I'm really not sure at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{ \{ e\in E_G : src(e) = v_1 \wedge tgt(e) = v_2 \} : v_1,v_2 \in V_G \}$